# Will mb_strimwidth function clear the charset of the string?

Tags: php, character-encoding

```
echo mb_strimwidth("Amorós Test String", 0, 10, "...");
```

Outputs:

```
Amor&amp;oacute;s
```

Instead of

```
Amorós Test...
```

Comment: no. php will **NOT** decode/encode html entities without you explicitly telling it to do so.

Comment: The command you posted outputs "Amorós ...". That is a width of 10, as requested. This probably is an effect of your encoding settings in one of the components in your web stack.